# Library already added: Gradle Build

Tags: android, build, compilation, gradle, library-project

I've just updated my project with the new gradle build system.

After trying it several times i failed always with the same issue.

I have a project with many sub-library-projects. Those use the support-library-v4 and my main project uses it too.
After some search i found that i have to use the maven link:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
```

i've added this (and left the jar in the libs folder for eclipse compatiblity)
but got still the same error

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
        at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
        at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

I even tried to remove those libs in the /libs folder but no luck

I use the newest version of gradle "`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.4'`"
but no luck.

I hope someone has a better idea?

Here's my build-script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    compile project(':HoloGraphLibrary')
    compile project(':CardsUI')
    compile project(':Caldroid')
    compile project(':BetterPickers')
    compile project(':Crouton')
    compile project(':ShowcaseView')
    compile project(':AboutLibraries')
    compile project(':StyledDialogs')

    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0' 
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    compile files('libs/ActiveAndroid-3.3.jar') 
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar') 
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    sourceSets {

        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

and here's one build-script of one of my libs:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
//     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0' 
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i'm feeling a bit stupid right now.

I just tried it a last time with gradle clean build
and guess what it is working :)

So the trick with the maven repositories and a new clean
worked for me.

Sorry for the trouble. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure all your sub-libraries have the line

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

commented out?

Comment: I suggest that you also make sure you aren't accidentally referring to "com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0" in some projects and "com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.0" in others. Sometimes it's easy to get the v13 and r13 naming mixed up

Comment: @Greg that shouldn't be a problem. -v13 depends on -v4 instead of embedding -v4 (like the non artifact version does) so it shouldn't trigger a duplicate class.

Comment: I've commented it out in each sub-library.
I use the support library, nineoldandroids, and joda-time as maven dependency. I also have a .jar included (ActiveAndroid) which uses the support-library because it needs LruCache (http://www.activeandroid.com/). But even if this causes an error for the support-library i also get the same for nineoldandroids and joda-time. (is used in multiple libs too)

Comment: Ok here's a folder with all build fuilds and the settings.gradle i'Ve also added the complete build output:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bz8fgfxyuy8ie3y/pvxBrzSxn5